# this is a single row of dataset how can we differentiate the all data above year 2020 in one csv and rest to drop or store in another csv

Tags: pandas, data-analysis

```
0   Ahmedabad   2015-01-01  NaN NaN 0.92    18.22   17.15   NaN 0.92    27.64   133.36  0.00    0.02    0.00    NaN
```

this is a single row of dataset how can we differentiate the all data above year 2020 in one CSV and rest to drop or store in another CSV

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the name of your dataframe is `df` and dates are in the column named `df['date']`, try these steps

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64')
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year

df1 = df[df['year'] >= 2020]
df2 = df[df['year'] < 2020]
 
df1.to_csv('above_2020.csv')
df2.to_csv('below_2020.csv')
```

Now `above_2020.csv` and `below_2020.csv` files are created in your working directory. Let me know if it worked or not